# Two closed operators satisfy $D(T_1)\subset D(T_2)$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

> **Question:** Let $\mathscr X, \mathscr X_1, \mathscr X_2$ be three Banach spaces, and $T_1$, $T_2$ be closed operators from $\mathscr X$ to $\mathscr X_1 $and $\mathscr X_2$, respectively, satisfy
> $$D(T_1)\subset D(T_2)\,.$$ where $D(T)$ denotes the domain of $T$.
> Prove that there exists a $C>0$, such that
> $$\left\Vert T_2 x\right\Vert_{\mathscr X_2}\leq C\left(\Vert x\Vert_{\mathscr X}+\Vert T_1 x\Vert_{\mathscr X_1}\right).$$

I have searched for the solution to it for a long time, but I still have no idea how answer it. Please do me a favor! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a direct application of closed graph theorem. Let's denote $\Gamma_i = \{(x,T_ix): x \in D(T_i)\}$ - graphs of your operators. Theese are banach spaces in the sense of graph norms $||(x,T_ix)|| = ||x||_{\mathscr{X}} + ||T_ix||_{\mathscr{X}_i}$. Now consider operator $S:\Gamma_1 \rightarrow \Gamma_2$ that acts as follows: $S(x,T_1x) = (x,T_2x)$ ($S$ is well defined since $D(T_1) \subset D(T_2)$). It is easy to see that your initial statement is equivalent to continuity of $S$ in graph norms.

Now we prove that $S$ is continuous by closed graph theorem. Let 
$$
z_n = \left((x_n,T_1x_n),(x_n, T_2x_n)\right) \rightarrow ((x,t),(x,s))
$$
be a converging sequence in $\Gamma_1 \oplus \Gamma_2$. Then $(x_n,T_ix_n)$ converges to some point $(x,T_ix)$ in $\Gamma_i$. But then we have $t = T_1x$ and $s = T_2x$ and therefore $((x,t),(x,s))$ belongs to graph of $S$. So, graph of $S$ is closed and $S$ is continuous.

Now we have some constant $C = ||S||$ such that $||(x,T_2x)|| \le C||(x,T_1x)||$ for all $x \in D(T_1)$. So 
$$||x||_{\mathscr{X}} + ||T_2x||_{\mathscr{X}_2} \le C(||x||_{\mathscr{X}} + ||T_1x||_{\mathscr{X}_1})$$
Then your inequality holds with the same constant $C$.

Comment: It’s a nice answer, thanks very much!